# How to correctly filter by timestamp in firestore

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, timestamp

I want to filter 'createdTime' is same, after, or before than given date. createdTome save as timestamp.

but it's only work for the following scenario:

```
const jobRef = firestore1.collection("jobs");
const data = await jobRef.
where('createdTime', '==', "12/08/2012" ).get();
```

it's not work for

```
where('createdTime', '>', "10/08/2012" ).get();
```

and

```
where('createdTime', '<', "10/08/2012" ).get();
```

Can someone explain how to correctly filter?

I hear attach firestore connection

[image]

Comment: I don't see that you have a field called "container.createdTime" in your document.  If you did, it wouldn't work for date comparison if the date was formatted as a string like mm/yy/dddd.

Comment: You can't compare a string to a timestamp.  You have to provide a Date or Timestamp object to the query to get a correct comparison.